# How do I build a chatbot that retrieves answers to specific questions that are saved on an excel spreadsheet database?

Tags: python, excel, chatbot, chatterbot

I am very new to python and am trying to build a chat bot that can retrieve specific answers to questions or phrases input from the user e.g.

Question/Phrase: Car model 1
Answer: BMW

Questions/Phrase: Car model 2
Answer: Tesla

I want the chat bot to return only the answer specified in the excel spreadsheet database that is associated to the question/phrase.

I have followed an online tutorial to build a basic chatbot and uses corpus data to generate responses but I would like to confine the results from the chat bot to an excel database.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from cleaner import clean_corpus

# Uncomment the below to remove/delete previous training
# chatbot = ChatBot("BOT")
# chatbot.storage.drop()


CORPUS_FILE = "history.yml"

chatbot = ChatBot("BOT")

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)
cleaned_corpus = clean_corpus(CORPUS_FILE)
trainer.train(cleaned_corpus)
exit_conditions = (":q", "quit", "exit")
while True:
   query = input("> ")
if query in exit_conditions:
    break
else:
    print(f" {chatbot.get_response(query)}")
```

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? What is the problem to keep question and answer on some list and later use `pandas.to_excel()` to other module to write in Excel (or at least in CSV)

Comment: if you follow some tutorial then in question (not in comments) you could add link to this tutorial

Comment: Hi @furas, I've added the code to the post, when this is run it returns random answers to questions based on what the bot is asked. I want the returned answers to be specifically called from an excel question = answer spreadsheet. I'm sure its an easy task for most but I am still learning and trying to understand the logic of how to make it work. hope you can help

Comment: if you want answer exactly from excel file then maybe load it as normal dictionary `dat a= {"Car model 1": "BMW", ...}` and use normal if/else instead of `ListTrainer` - ie. `if question in data: answer = data[question]`